Convert .xlsx file exceeding file size to Google Sheets
An .xlsx file is generated by a separate team, usually around 55mb, and uploaded to a Google Drive folder. There is only one tab (which does include some references) that is relevant to me, and the end goal is to have only that tab (pasted as values) in a separate Google sheet that I can pull values from. My current plan is:

Convert the .xlsx file to Google Sheet, so I can operate on it using Apps Script.
Copy the one relevant tab to a static Google Sheet, which will be overwritten with the new data each week. This will be referenced to.

I've already written most of the code, which works, but I'm facing issues with the file size limit of 50mb. I have a script below which successfully converts .xlsx files to Google Sheet format (tested), but fails on this specific file since it's ~55mb.
function convertExceltoGoogleSpreadsheet2(fileName) {
  try {
    fileName = fileName || 'filename.xlsx';

    var excelFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next();
    var fileId = excelFile.getId();
    var folderId = Drive.Files.get(fileId).parents[0].id;
    var blob = excelFile.getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: excelFile.getName().replace(/\.xlsx?/, ''),
      key: fileId,
    };
    Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, {
      convert: true,
    });
  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}

Is there any workaround here, assuming I have no say in the source data process or file generation? I have thought about converting the .xlsx file to .csv to reduce the file size, but that doesn't work as I can't even touch it since it exceeds the maximum file size. Is there a way to somehow just extract one tab as values into a different sheet to bypass the file size limit? I'm sure there is a way to get around this, but can't figure it out. If I can access the file somehow within Apps Script I can do the rest.

Unfortunately, no workaround is available based only on Google Apps Script Drive or Advanced Drive services.
Workarounds
1. Split the Excel file
Using Excel or a compatible application to handle the file, split it before uploading it to Google Drive.

First, create a new Excel file for each sheet.
If the new Excel files are still too big, split them into multiple parts to get file sizes less than the file size limits.

2. Use Google Cloud Platform
One option is to use Google Cloud Storage, Big Query, and the built-in Google Sheets feature to query data from Big Query.
Preparation: If you haven't already created a Google Cloud Platform account, start with this. You might be asked to create a billing account to be able to use some GCP services, even for using the free tier, but you might get some credits. As a new user, you will be asked to create a new GCP project.

Upload the file to Google Cloud Storage.
Import it into Google Big Query.
Pull the Google Big Query data into a Google Sheets spreadsheet.

3. Use another programming platform with Google APIs.
You might use another programming language / platform to automate the Excel file splitting, Google Sheets API, Google Drive API, or Google Apps Script API to create the Google Sheets spreadsheets you need or push the data to existing spreadsheets.
Related

Upload automatically a large file for bigquery processing
Is there any way to convert a a large Excel CSV file to Google Sheet in Google App Maker?
Workaround solutions to Google App Script "Exception: FILENAME.csv exceeds the maxmium file size"?

